# Ehcache 3.0, example of a eviction adviser?

Tags: spring, ehcache

So I'm upgrading a spring boot project to use the latest version of ehcache (3.0). However, I can't seem to find what I want. I want to be able to set the eviction policy to LRU, however I can't seem to find any eviction policies in the docs. In the link they talk about the OddKeysEvictionAdvisor. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/eviction-advisor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ehcache 3.0.x there is no configurable eviction policy.

The *eviction advisor* really is a way to hint that some cache mappings should be kept over others, and as the API shows, this does not include mapping metadata, only key and value.